# How do I make nested_attributes work in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

Here's my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :teacher, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :teacher_attributes
end
```

Here's my teacher model:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :user_id, :first_name, :last_name
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :first_name, :last_name
end
```

Here's my form:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => registration_path(:user)) do |user| %>


        <%= user.text_field :email %>
        <%= user.text_field :password %>
        <%= user.text_field :password_confirmation %>


    <%= user.fields_for resource.build_teacher do |t| %>
            <%= t.text_field :first_name %>
            <%= t.text_field :last_name %>
            <%= t.text_field :phone %>
    <% end %>

      <%= user.submit 'Confirm' %>
<% end %>
```

Except that this thing won't "accept nested attributes"
My development log says:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: teacher
```

I don't know if it's related, but the form isn't generating fields inside a teacher_attributes array or anything - it's inside teacher. I'm guessing that's where my problem is, but I don't how to make it put the fields inside it. Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these things:

At top of view:

```
<% @user.build_teacher if @user.teacher.nil? %>
```

For the fields for:

```
<%= user.fields_for :teacher do |t| %>
```

Also, personally, I like naming the block parameters in forms (the part `|user|` and `|t|`) as `|form|` (because when you're having a long day, and you see `user` down in the view and not `form`, it can confuse you!)

Comment: I love you. I'm literally shedding tears now.WHYYY did this line cost me 4 hours of my life? WHYYYYYYY?

Comment: Sometimes you need a second set of eyes and it turns out to be a problem that's so simple. I've been in same situation and I realized that if you step back and do something else and come back to the problem later with aim to analyze instead of poking around, then it helps a great deal! And of course, nothing beats a few good books on Rails.

Comment: +1 on that one. All I needed was some sleep and then things started moving along much faster. Thanks for the helpful answer and good advice.